# Where is the best place to keep authorization server in microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am designing a set of microservices for user management, api gateway, cart & checkout, promotions etc (ecommerce services). Planning to manage authentication and authorization using jwt token. Which service would be the best place to keep the authorization server?
I have refered a few designs where its found on the api gateway, but I need a separate user management service and users table is maintained here (other services like cart checkout etc would be resource servers) Grant types: client_credentials and password are required.
Are there any existing open source projects I can refer? Any documentation available for best practives?

Comment: If you are familiar with spring framework I would suggest https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ This project provides an oauth2 authorization server. Recently I saw they specifically created an new project called https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are maintaining user data alongwith with the Authorization server, I woud suggest you to register this as a separate micro-service as `AuthService` in your `RegistryService`.

Best practice should be to use a JDBCTokenStore so that user is authenticated even if service instance get stopped or disrupted.

You shall include a dedicated DB for this service that shall include tables for User details, grant authorities, access tokens and refresh tokens.